# How to animate the second value of the stdDeviation attribute with gsap?

Tags: animation, svg, attributes, gsap

Is it possible to animate the second value of the stdDeviation attribute?

Actually Gsap allows to animate numerical attribute like stdDeviation :

```
.to(blurNode, 0.5, {attr:{stdDeviation:20}, "blur")
```

But in the case of the stdDeviation we can have 2 values like so :

```
<feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="0 0" />
```

Is it possible to animate only the second value?

Answer (score 0):

Sure, it should be as simple as:

```
TweenMax.to("#test", 5, {attr:{stdDeviation:"0 20"}});
```

Here's a demo: 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KgrZKK?editors=1010#

(Just make sure you've got a relatively recent version of GSAP)